# how to turn a wide table into a long table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a wide table that looks like this:

| Case REFERENCE | OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION | MONTH1_EMP_SITUATION | MONTH1_REASON | MONTH3_EMP_SITUATION | MONTH3_REASON | MONTH6_EMP_SITUATION | MONTH6_REASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Employed | Employed | Outcome at 1 month | Employed | Outcome at 3 month | Employed | Outcome at 6 month |

this is survey results that people completed after they finished employment program. They complete the survey 4 times, once immediately after finishing the program, and then after 1/3/6 month. the problem is, the results for immediately after program completion are in one table (Outcome table) and the 1/3/6 month checkpoint results are in another table (Checkpointinfo table) I would like to combine those tables to create a long table so that instead of having "Outcome" in 5 different columns, I would have it in one column and it would look like this:

| Case Reference | Outcome_emp_situation | Month_Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Employed | NULL |
| 12345 | Employed | Outcome at 1 month |
| 12345 | Employed | Outcome at 3 month |
| 12345 | Employed | Outcome at 6 month |

I was wondering if anyone could please help me out to turn this wide query into a long table query.

Here is the query for the wide table:

```
Select                                      
ch.CASEREFERENCE, oc.OUTCOME_DATE, oc.OUTCOME_REFERENCE_ID, oc.OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION, oc.OUTCOME_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE, oc.OUTCOME_NUM_JOBS, oc.OUTCOME_NAICS_DESC, oc.OUTCOME_JOB_NATURE,                                        
oc.OUTCOME_WORK_HOURS, oc.OUTCOME_WAGE, oc.OUTCOME_STUDENT_STATUS, oc.OUTCOME_GOT_SERVICE,  oc.OUTCOME_RIGHT_SERVICE, oc.OUTCOME_RECOMMEND_PROGRAM,                                         
ck1.REASONCODE AS REASONCODE1,                                      
CASE WHEN ck1.REASONCODE = 'OT1' THEN "Outcome at 1 month" END MONTH1_REASON,                                       
ck1.MONTH_START_DATE AS MONTH1_START_DATE, ck1.MONTH_END_DATE AS MONTH1_END_DATE, ck1.MONTH_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION AS MONTH1_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION,                                      
ck1.MONTH_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE AS MONTH1_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE, ck1.MONTH_NUM_JOBS AS ,MONTH1_NUM_JOBS, ck1.MONTH_NAICS_DESC AS MONTH1_NAICS_DESC, ck1.MONTH_JOB_NATURE AS MONTH1_JOB_NATURE,                                      
ck1.MONTH_WORK_HOURS AS MONTH1_WORK_HOURS, ck1.MONTH_WAGE AS MONTH1_WAGE, ck1.MONTH_STUDENT_STATUS AS MONTH1_STUDENT_STATUS, ck1.MONTH_GOT_SERVICE AS MONTH1_GOT_SERVICE,                                       
ck1.MONTH_RIGHT_SERVICE AS MONTH1_RIGHT_SERVICE, ck1.MONTH_RECOMMEND_PROGRAM AS MONTH1_RECOMMEND_PROGRAM, ck1.MONTH_RESUBMIT_MILESTONE AS MONTH1_RESUBMIT_MILESTONE,                                        
ck1.MONTH_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED AS MONTH1_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED, ck1.MONTH_APPROVED_DATE AS MONTH1_APPROVED_DATE,                                     
ck3.REASONCODE AS REASONCODE3,                                      
CASE WHEN ck3.REASONCODE = 'OT3' THEN "Outcome at 3 month" END MONTH3_REASON,                                       
ck3.MONTH_START_DATE AS MONTH3_START_DATE, ck3.MONTH_END_DATE AS MONTH3_END_DATE, ck3.MONTH_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION AS MONTH3_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION,                                      
ck3.MONTH_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE AS MONTH3_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE, ck3.MONTH_NUM_JOBS AS ,MONTH3_NUM_JOBS, ck3.MONTH_NAICS_DESC AS MONTH3_NAICS_DESC, ck3.MONTH_JOB_NATURE AS MONTH3_JOB_NATURE,                                      
ck3.MONTH_WORK_HOURS AS MONTH3_WORK_HOURS, ck3.MONTH_WAGE AS MONTH3_WAGE, ck3.MONTH_STUDENT_STATUS AS MONTH3_STUDENT_STATUS, ck3.MONTH_GOT_SERVICE AS MONTH3_GOT_SERVICE,                                       
ck3.MONTH_RIGHT_SERVICE AS MONTH3_RIGHT_SERVICE, ck3.MONTH_RECOMMEND_PROGRAM AS MONTH3_RECOMMEND_PROGRAM, ck3.MONTH_RESUBMIT_MILESTONE AS MONTH3_RESUBMIT_MILESTONE,                                        
ck3.MONTH_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED AS MONTH3_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED, ck3.MONTH_APPROVED_DATE AS MONTH3_APPROVED_DATE,                                     
ck6.REASONCODE AS REASONCODE6,                                      
CASE WHEN ck6.REASONCODE = 'OT6' THEN "Outcome at 6 month" END MONTH6_REASON,                                       
ck6.MONTH_START_DATE AS MONTH6_START_DATE, ck6.MONTH_END_DATE AS MONTH6_END_DATE, ck6.MONTH_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION AS MONTH6_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION,                                      
ck6.MONTH_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE AS MONTH6_EMPLOYMENT_TYPE, ck6.MONTH_NUM_JOBS AS ,MONTH6_NUM_JOBS, ck6.MONTH_NAICS_DESC AS MONTH6_NAICS_DESC, ck6.MONTH_JOB_NATURE AS MONTH6_JOB_NATURE,                                      
ck6.MONTH_WORK_HOURS AS MONTH6_WORK_HOURS, ck6.MONTH_WAGE AS MONTH6_WAGE, ck6.MONTH_STUDENT_STATUS AS MONTH6_STUDENT_STATUS, ck6.MONTH_GOT_SERVICE AS MONTH6_GOT_SERVICE,                                       
ck6.MONTH_RIGHT_SERVICE AS MONTH6_RIGHT_SERVICE, ck6.MONTH_RECOMMEND_PROGRAM AS MONTH6_RECOMMEND_PROGRAM, ck6.MONTH_RESUBMIT_MILESTONE AS MONTH6_RESUBMIT_MILESTONE,                                        
ck6.MONTH_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED AS MONTH6_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED, ck6.MONTH_APPROVED_DATE AS MONTH6_APPROVED_DATE                                      
FROM PROGRAM as pg                                      
LEFT JOIN CASEINFO as ch ON pg.CASEID = ch.CASEID                                       
LEFT JOIN OUTCOME as oc ON pg.CASEID = oc.CASEID                                        
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cp.CASEID, cp.REASONCODE, cp.MONTH_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION, cpi.*  FROM CHECKPOINT cp LEFT JOIN CHECKPOINTINFO cpi ON cp.CASEREVIEWID = cpi.CASEREVIEWID WHERE cpi.REASONCODE = 'OT1')ck1 ON pg.CASEID = ck1.CASEID                                        
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cp.CASEID, cp.REASONCODE, cp.MONTH_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION, cpi.*  FROM CHECKPOINT cp LEFT JOIN CHECKPOINTINFO cpi ON cp.CASEREVIEWID = cpi.CASEREVIEWID WHERE cpi.REASONCODE = 'OT3')ck3 ON pg.CASEID = ck3.CASEID                                        
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cp.CASEID, cp.REASONCODE, cp.MONTH_OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION, cpi.*  FROM CHECKPOINT cp LEFT JOIN CHECKPOINTINFO cpi ON cp.CASEREVIEWID = cpi.CASEREVIEWID WHERE cpi.REASONCODE = 'OT6')ck6 ON pg.CASEID = ck6.CASEID
```

If someone could please help me turn this wide table into a long table, it would be much appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to do [`unpivot`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDJBHHI) for outcome and reason columns. But first you need an extra column for overall reason. This is the query:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 12345 as case_reference,
>     'Employed' as OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION,
>     'Employed' as MONTH1_EMP_SITUATION,
>     'Outcome at 1 month' as MONTH1_REASON,
>     'Employed' as MONTH3_EMP_SITUATION,
>     'Outcome at 3 month' as MONTH3_REASON,
>     'Employed' as MONTH6_EMP_SITUATION,
>     'Outcome at 6 month' as MONTH6_REASON
>   from dual
> )
> select
>   case_reference,
>   outcome_emp_situation,
>   month_reason
> from (
>   select a.*,
>     cast(null as varchar2(1000)) as reason
>   from a
> ) a
> unpivot(
>   (Outcome_emp_situation, Month_Reason)
>   for mon in (
>     (OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION, reason) as 0,
>     (MONTH1_EMP_SITUATION, MONTH1_REASON) as 1,
>     (MONTH3_EMP_SITUATION, MONTH3_REASON) as 3,
>     (MONTH6_EMP_SITUATION, MONTH6_REASON) as 6
>   )
> )
> order by mon asc
> ```
>
> ```
> CASE_REFERENCE | OUTCOME_EMP_SITUATION | MONTH_REASON      
> -------------: | :-------------------- | :-----------------
>          12345 | Employed              | null              
>          12345 | Employed              | Outcome at 1 month
>          12345 | Employed              | Outcome at 3 month
>          12345 | Employed              | Outcome at 6 month
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c97646af2148710462c6eadf0e98b4cf)*

**UPD**: The explanation below.

The tuple just after `unpivot` keyword is the result column names, column after `for` keyword identifies column group which produced that values. Tuples inside `in` define the columns' groups: for each group that columns' values will be passed to the corresponding (by position) columns of the result tuple and new row will be generated with the value of `for` column defined after `as` keyword.

So if you need more columns to be transferred to each row, you need to add new columns to the result tuple (after `unpivot`) and to **each** column group inside `in`. If for some reason you have not enough columns to pass for some groups, you can wrap your source query with outer `select` and add dummy (or constantly valued) columns for that groups.

Note:

- Datatypes of each tuples should be the same (or convertible according to [default datatype precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51044)). I.e. each tuple's member on the same position should have the same type, members at different positions may have different types.
- You can reuse the same column in multiple groups and positions.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the wide table query to get the same results? Because I just need to turn the query I posted into a long table query. Thank you

Comment: Create a query that returns your initial results. Then place it into `with` (in my case, it is `with a as ...`). The rest part is in the answer.

Comment: okay so do I do the same thing to the other columns as well such as month1_job_nature, month3_job_nature, Month6_job_nature and so forth?

Comment: @ops_mltsd I've updated my answer with more explanation of this process. In short: yes, add as much columns as you need to each group and to the result tuple.